# How to execute PostgreSQL query using Powershell ISE

Tags: postgresql, powershell

Geeks!,
I want to execute the SQL queries below by a script in powershell ISE.
This is a sql function already written

select UserAndRoleInsert('test@email.com','VesselName','Master','Vessel Master');
select ClientInsert();

How can I connect with postgres sever using powershell code ?
server is 'test123'
Database is 'IdentityAdmin_Shore'
In localhost

Answer (score 0):

You can try below:

1. Install `Postgresql ODBC driver`.
2. Make sure your system recognizes the driver. For example, if your system is Windows then add DSN in the `ODBC Datasource Admin`.

   [image]
   3. Then try executing the code(Though I haven't tested it from my end). You can store the user id and password in a config file.

   ```
    $DBConnectionString = "Driver={PostgreSQL Unicode(x64)}:Server=<server>;Port=<port>;Database=$MyDB;Uid=<userid>;Pwd=<pass>;"
    $DBConn = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection;
    $DBConn.ConnectionString = $DBConnectionString;
    $DBConn.Open();
    $DBCmd = $DBConn.CreateCommand();
    $DBCmd.CommandText = "<query1>;<query2>;";
    $DBCmd.ExecuteReader();
    $DBConn.Close();
   ```